# Using Equally == 0 in Ruby on Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Not sure how to phrase my question. I have an event model and one of the fields is called 'state'. I would like to have a condition in my view where i can use the state of the event to display a message.

The default field value is '0'. and i have a few events already. My code looks something likfe this. But nothing happens. Am i missing something? i have also tried to use > 0

```
<% if event.state == 0 %> 
    <p> I will print a message here </p>
<% end%>
```

Am i missing something here?

Comment: is the value an integer or a string?

Comment: It's an integer.  state int(11)

Comment: What is output if you do `<% Rails.logger.debug(event.state) %>` just before the `if`?

Comment: @ScottJShea , Thanks a lot for this. I have another model called state (where i stored the country states) and it was causing a conflict. I have then changed my field "state" to "eventstate" now everything works.

Comment: @Vezu glad I could help. I have made similar errors myself

Answer (score 0):

Is the state stored as a varchar or an integer? If varchar, try doing

`if event.state == "0"`

Comment: Just changed it to varchar and then tried your suggestion but no luck.

Comment: What happens when you go into your console and just print out `event.state`? Try running `.class` on that output and see what class it's outputting.

Answer (score 0):

What is the data type of your state?

If its stored as string then try `if event.state.eql?"0"`

For more on conditional check of string see [Ruby String API](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/String.html#method-i-eql-3F)

Steps to identify what might be the problem.

1. Check whether event is present or not? by `raise event.inspect`
2. Check the class of the event.state `puts event.state.class.name.inspect`